# Search for values ​in an array with one condition

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have one array of players

and so I wanted to create a function to match each other following a condition

I started by thinking (get the first player on the queue) and trying to find another player that meets the condition

But then I thought: If I don't match the first player, I will never move to the second match

basically i need to get 2 players from a queue that meet a condition regardless of their position in the queue

```
  searching(id) {
    const firstPLayer = this.players.find(p => p.id == id)
    const { mmr } = firstPLayer
    const secondPlayer = this.players.find((playerTwo) => playerTwo.mmr < (5 / 100) * mmr + mmr && playerTwo.mmr > mmr - ((5 / 100) * mmr) && playerTwo.id != firstPLayer.id);
    if(!secondPlayer){
      return null;
    }
    const matchedPlayers = [
      firstPLayer,
      secondPlayer
    ]
    // remove matched players from this.players
    this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
    // return new Match with matched players
    return matchedPlayers;
  }
```

Something like this, I have two conditions |:

> playerTwo.mmr <(5/100) * mmr + mmr && playerTwo.mmr> mmr - ((5/100) *
>   mmr)

but in case I need to fetch two players with this condition without passing the first player

Comment: So, filter on the condition and then `slice(0, 2)` the results?

Comment: I didn't understand well

Comment: In case I would filter with my condition
 and would use slicar to return a new array?

sounds interesting to me but i don't know how i would apply it with my condition and taking 2 players from the queue

I posted a code that I use to pair by passing a player

Comment: plis help me :(

Comment: Slice sounds like a good idea
but I don't know how I would filter 2 players from this queue according to one condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell why it is not working for you (are you sure there are even 2 players that match your parameters within your players list?)..

You can use the following example to help you, as it seems to be working for me.

```js
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.players = fetchPlayers();
  }
  
  removePlayers(playersToRemove) {
    playersToRemove.forEach(player => {
      const index = this.players.indexOf(player);
      this.players.splice(index, 1);
    })
  }
  
  getRandomPlayer() {
    return this.players[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.players.length)];
  }
  
  calculateLessThanPercentage(player) {
    return 5 / 100 * player.mmr + player.mmr 
  }
    
  calculateGreaterThanPercentage(player) {
    return player.mmr - 5 / 100 * player.mmr
  }

  searching() {
    const firstPlayer = this.getRandomPlayer();
    
    const secondPlayer = this.players.find(
      playerTwo =>
        playerTwo.mmr < this.calculateLessThanPercentage(firstPlayer) &&
        playerTwo.mmr > this.calculateGreaterThanPercentage(firstPlayer) &&
        playerTwo.id != firstPlayer.id
    );
    
    if (!secondPlayer) {
      return null;
    }
    
    const matchedPlayers = [firstPlayer, secondPlayer];
    this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
    return matchedPlayers;
  }
}

const ActiveQueue = new Queue();

const getPlayersButton = document.getElementById("getPlayers");
const playersResults = document.getElementById("players");
const allPlayers = document.getElementById("allPlayers");

getPlayersButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  getPlayers(ActiveQueue, playersResults, allPlayers)
});

// getPlayersButton click event handler
function getPlayers(queue, resultsElement, allPlayersElement) {
  const searchResults = queue.searching();
  resultsElement.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(searchResults, null, 2);
  allPlayersElement.innerHTML = "Remaining Players: " + JSON.stringify(queue.players, null, 2);
}

// to get data
function fetchPlayers() {
  return [
    {
      name: "Player One",
      id: 1,
      mmr: 500
    },
    {
      name: "Player Two",
      id: 2,
      mmr: 800
    },
    {
      name: "Player Three",
      id: 3,
      mmr: 810
    },
    {
      name: "Player Four",
      id: 4,
      mmr: 815
    },
    {
      name: "Player Five",
      id: 5,
      mmr: 510
    },
    {
      name: "Player Six",
      id: 6,
      mmr: 540
    },
    {
      name: "Player Seven",
      id: 7,
      mmr: 530
    },
    {
      name: "Player Eight",
      id: 8,
      mmr: 520
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
Click to get players (scroll all the way down to see remaining players)
<br />
<button id="getPlayers">Get Players</button>
<pre id="players"></pre>
<br />
<hr />
<pre id="allPlayers"></pre>
```

Comment: Sorry if I spelled it wrong

But my example works, I just showed what I had done

but my goal is to form a match without having to pass the player id

form a match according to the queue with my two conditions

Comment: I need to match 2 players in my row
if they have mmr between 5% or -5% of your mmr

Comment: Slice sounds like a good idea
but I don't know how I would filter 2 players from this queue according to one condition

Comment: So you are wanting to find 2 players that are between +5% and -5% of eachother? Just 2 random players that meet that condition?

Comment: @Felipe Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con algo que debería ayudarte con esto. (I just updated my answer with something that should help you with this).

Comment: I spent my whole day thinking about some possibility for this